# How to send Escape key using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, keypress

When user clicks some button on my MVC view, I want to simulate the event that gets executed on Escape key. How can I achieve it using JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function pressEsc() {
    $('body').trigger({
        type: 'keyup',
        which: 27 // Escape key
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('body').on('keyup', function (e) {
        alert(e.which + ' key was pressed');
    });

    // Press the escape key
    pressEsc();
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/T4H89/

Comment: thanks for the example, and source code. However, I do not find it working on my MVC view. Actually, I have a JQuery Dialog UI, and I want to send its Escape key on one of the button press. If I press escape simply, it closes the dialog, but sending keystroke does not seem to be working.

Comment: Ok, this actually is not supported in my JQuery version 1.6.4. Any idea for this particular version?

Comment: The fiddle is using 1.9.1. I imagine you can just replace `$('body').on('keyup', function...` with `$('body').keyup(function...`

Answer (score 1):

Simulate the keydown element with key code 27 (escape key).

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown"); 
e.which = 27;
$("#escape_button").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

this will detect the **ESC** key and it will trigger the defined event.

```
   $('body').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.which === 27) { // detect if it is **Esc** button
            alert("esc pressed now triggering event");
            $(".a").trigger("click"); //trigger event
        }
    });
```